# calendar extender entering today's date defaultly in textbox(when i click on calendar image to open the calendar)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, textbox, asp.net-ajax, calendarextender

I am using a **textbox** with **calendar extender**. My problem is, when i click on **calendar image**(to open the calendar), **today's** date is defaultly coming in **textbox**

here is my code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" runat="server" Width="70px" CssClass="txt_box"></asp:TextBox>

<input type="image" id="ImageStart" runat="server" src="~/images/date-picker-icon.jpg" />

<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" TargetControlID="txtExpiryDate" MaskType="Date" Mask="99/99/9999" runat="server"></cc1:MaskedEditExtender>     

<cc1:calendarextender ID="Calendarextender2" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateSelectionChanged" OnClientShown="clientShown" TargetControlID="txtExpiryDate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageStart" Enabled="true" runat="server"> </cc1:calendarextender>
```

how to solve this issue..

Please Help.

Comment: Is the js-function `clientShown` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you've copied the markup of your `CalendarExtender` from somewhere but without the javascript function `clientShown`.

This registers the (clientside) event:

```
<cc1:calendarextender ID="Calendarextender2"
    OnClientShown="clientShown" ...
```

So either remove that event declaration or create the function.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientShown(sender, args) {
        var extender= $find('Calendarextender2');
        // the following is just for demonstration
        //sender.set_visibleDate(extender._selectedDate);
        //sender.set_todaysDate(extender._selectedDate);
        //sender.set_selectedDate(extender._selectedDate);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh... thank you very much. i removed `OnClientShown="clientShown"` and now it's working fine..

Comment: i have **clientshown** function in javascript. But in that function we are adding today's date to textbox directly(when clicking on calendar extender). this is the reason why i am getting current date defaultly in textbox. now i removed the onClientShown attribute and it's working fine now. Thank you.now i got the clear idea on it :-)

Comment: @RanadheerReddy: I'm glad to hear that you've got it working now. As you can see i've added some of the extender functions and properties(nowhere documented, found them with js debugging). They might be helpful for you sometime.